# How to correctly persist and present information from multiple aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I'm creating a selling platform. The core aggregate is called Announcement and it holds references to other aggregates such as Categories, User etc. I am using CQRS approach an event-sourcing solution as storage.

For performance reasons, I decided to store some important details about associated objects (Categories, User) inside the Announcement aggregate along with their ids. My reasoning behind it was that when filtering announcements, I want to simplify the access to those information as much as possible (reduce the number of database joins, allow fancy querying syntax). It was possible, because I included all the required information in the command, which creates an announcement. Generation of a detailed view of an announcement is based on information embedded inside the aggregate. Although it seemed reasonable at first, now I'm having second thoughts.

The considerations that made me think are:

- I realized that I don't need transactional consistency on all the additional details (categories, seller details, etc.). There are no constraints that would force me to do what I did.
- The event store that I'm using offers multistream projections. I'm wondering if that's the puzzle piece that should replace the redundant information in the Announcement aggregate.

Are the following steps a valid solution for the described problem?

1. Remove the duplicated information from the Announcement aggregate;
2. Use a domain event to notify other aggregates about creation of an Announcement;
3. Let other aggregates publish appropriate events in response to the AnnouncementCreated event; these events may contain additional information about associated objects;
4. Introduce a multistream projection, which will update itself in response to events from multiple aggregates and produce a complete view of the announcement;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the only reason to include data in a particular aggregate is if that data affects command validation or if there's some other consistency demand.  if information about categories or users isn't qualifying under either reason, then it makes a lot of sense to remove it from the announcement aggregate.

I would probably consider modeling a "categorized and associated announcement" aggregate which is fed by domain events from announcement/category/user aggregates.  This could be implemented via the multistream projection from your event store, but I think it's useful to keep that detail separate because there are other ways you could feed domain events from multiple aggregates as commands for a different aggregate (the command implicit in any event is "incorporate this event into your view of the world").

Comment: Thanks, Levi. What makes the case more complicated is the fact that the very first CreateAnnouncement command comes with a bunch of IDs of other aggregates. So what I get is already a "categorized and associated announcement". I'm reluctant to saving it with unverified IDs, so I need to validate them first. Since I'm new to DDD and CQRS, I'm not sure if it's ok to send a series of queries before I commit the transaction which creates the announcement. If that were the case, I guess that feeding the view could be done afterwards, perhaps using a saga. What do you think?

Comment: If all you need to validate is that the IDs are of other entities that actually exist, it's worth considering having a read-side or read-sides which efficiently answer the "does this category/user exist" or even "do all of these categories/users exist" queries.  I don't think it's that unreasonable to query that read-side (which can be fed just by subscribing to the domain events from category/user and ignoring nearly all of them).

Comment: I read a bit and I see that there are a few approaches to this, one of them being the service for "chatting" with other aggregates. I've read a lot about why http calls are not the best solution for communicating between microservices. What about accepting those IDs and running a saga to validate them afterwards? After all, I don't think people will maliciously change them too often. Also, I don't want to become too paranoid about every request which comes to the system... or should I? (I'm still referring to the part of the data that is not directly verifiable by the aggregate, like the IDs).

Comment: For the record, I've found a few sources likie [this](https://github.com/prooph/event-sourcing/issues/79#issuecomment-404480662) which say that "an AR should not care if IDs of other ARs actually exist (e.g. through "relations"). For that use a process manager". They helped me realize that a reactive way of handling errors is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Never design aggregates by thinking of how you will read data. That is against the purpose of CQRS. Aggregates are about commands and business rules not queries. Use events to gather data from multiple aggregates then project the data however you want without affecting your aggregates. This concept is called a "projection".

Comment: Sure, I agree, but I need to validate the command in the application level before I pass it on to the domain. The command is constructed based on information that I can not necessarily trust. I'm mainly talking about references to other aggregates.

Comment: "references to other aggregates" are just ids. Why would you like to validate that?